# TIME column with Carbon in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a 'timeAfter' column of type `TIME` in my MySQL database, created with the `QueryBuilder` as `$table->time('timeAfter');` and I've added the following to my Model:

```
public $timestamps = false;

public function getDates () {
    return array ('timeAfter');
}
```

But when I run my app I get the following error, it seems that the [Date Mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators) expects a `DATE` or `DATETIME` but not a `TIME` column.. Any idea?

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing
open:
...\vendor\nesbot\carbon\Carbon\Carbon.php
  }

  if ($dt instanceof \DateTime) {
     return self::instance($dt);
  }

  $errors = \DateTime::getLastErrors();
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException(implode(PHP_EOL, $errors['errors']));
}
public static function createFromTimestamp($timestamp, $tz = null)
```

Comment: Well, there's simply not enough information in the column to build a `DateTime` object. If you wish to do any specific conversion, you'll have to create your own mutator.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into the same issue. I Raphael_'s note and created a mutator and it worked fine. Carbon parsed the TIME column just fine.

```
public function getTimeAfterAttribute($value) {
    return Carbon::parse($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `Carbon::parse()` as used in @normany answer returned an exception:

```
Exception with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (50:00:00) at position 0 (5): Unexpected character'
```

so I had to change it to

```
return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value);
```

In my case, however, the `TIME` column can contain hours greater than 24. With `'50:00:00'`, the returned value is *the day after tomorrow, plus 2 hours*, which is not really what I needed.

Therefore, I changed the `getTimeAfterAttribute()` method as follow:

```
public function getTimeAfterAttribute($value)
{
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $value);
    return CarbonInterval::create(null, null, null, null, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

This way, with `'50:00:00'`, I get this `var_dump()` output:

```
 class Carbon\CarbonInterval#921 (15) {
  public $y =>
  int(0)
  public $m =>
  int(0)
  public $d =>
  int(0)
  public $h =>
  int(50)
  public $i =>
  int(0)
  public $s =>
  int(0)
  public $weekday =>
  int(0)
  public $weekday_behavior =>
  int(0)
  public $first_last_day_of =>
  int(0)
  public $invert =>
  int(0)
  public $days =>
  bool(false)
  public $special_type =>
  int(0)
  public $special_amount =>
  int(0)
  public $have_weekday_relative =>
  int(0)
  public $have_special_relative =>
  int(0)
}
```